# Filtering to the user accessing dinamically In power BI?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a page-filter where I have username and I have it with the “require single selection”

But, whenever each user logs to the report it sees username=Alan, because I published it with that filter fixed…. Is there a way I can change it so that whenever each user logs sees her/his own filter?

That is the filter should change based on who access it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. You can create individualized URLs for each user, which will set the filter when loaded (see [Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters)). Users can also create personal bookmarks with their name preselected in the filter (see [Bookmarks in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-bookmarks)), but you can't force this through the report itself. For example, what should happen, if someone loads the report anonymously from a [publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) link?

What you describe, looks more like implementing [Row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls) in the report, where you use [USERPRINCIPALNAME()](https://dax.guide/userprincipalname/) DAX function to filter the data visible to the viewer of the report.

Comment: I already have RLS in place and it doesn't help me. Because; for example we have the case of super-users who have access to multiple users; in that case, I want the super-user to see by default herself/himself...